# CORS error on railway production environment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, cors

I have configured my server to accept cors

```
var whitelist = ['http://localhost:5000', 'http://localhost:3000', "https://newfrontened-production.up.railway.app", 'https://projecttrackingexpressbackend-production.up.railway.app']
var corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    },
    credentials: true,

    methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
}
 
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

I have made a axios instace

```
export const axiosPrivate = axios.create({
    // // baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Set-Cookie'
    },
    withCredentials: true
});
```

howeve when i try to make a request i having a 401 error and the the cookies are not being sent with the response as well.

This is the request from the client

```
export const getAllProjects = async () => {
    // the all the projects from the  deployed api 
    const projects = await axiosPrivate.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_EXPRESS}/projects`, {
        withCredentials: true
    });

    // console.log(projects);
    return projects
}
```

Comment: None of those `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers belong in a request.

Comment: so what do I do ?

Comment: @tatendafambirachimwe Drop all those headers from your request; leave only the `content-type` request header. After that, try running the updated client code. Do you get a CORS error then? If so, edit your question and add the CORS error message.